# Removing specific sublists

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a program that generates a list of specific 3-tuples of integers. A typical output is as follows:

```
list = {{0, 0, 2}, {0, 1, 1}, {0, 2, 0}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 0}, {2, 0, 0}}
```

I want to remove all 3-tuples `{x_,y_,z_}` where $x$ or $y$ (or both) are odd. The output in the example should be

```
cleanlist = {{0,0,2},{0,2,0},{2,0,0}}
```

Note that 1 isn't the only odd integer that can appear.

I tried using something like `cleanlist = DeleteCases[DeleteCases[list, {_OddQ,y_,z_}],{x_,_OddQ,z_}]`, but unfortunately `OddQ` doesn't behave like `Integer`.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Try `DeleteCases[list, {_?OddQ, _, _} | {_, _?OddQ, _}]` and report back.

Comment: It works, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

```
Cases[{__?EvenQ, _}] @ list
```

> ```
> {{0, 0, 2}, {0, 2, 0}, {2, 0, 0}}
> ```

```
DeleteCases[Except @ {__?EvenQ, _}] @ list
```

> ```
> {{0, 0, 2}, {0, 2, 0}, {2, 0, 0}}
> ```

```
Select[Apply[And] @* EvenQ @* Most] @ list
```

> ```
> {{0, 0, 2}, {0, 2, 0}, {2, 0, 0}}
> ```

```
GroupBy[Total[Mod[ #, 2]] &][list][0]
```

> ```
>  {{0, 0, 2}, {0, 2, 0}, {2, 0, 0}}
> ```

Answer (score 5):

```
Pick[list, Mod[list[[All, 1 ;; 2]], 2].{1, 1}, 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

The other way around

```
p = {OrderlessPatternSequence[_?OddQ, _], _};
```

Using `SequenceSplit` (new in 11.3)

```
Join @@ SequenceSplit[list, {p}]
```

{{0, 0, 2}, {0, 2, 0}, {2, 0, 0}}

Using `ReplaceAt` (new in 13.1)

```
ReplaceAt[_ :> Nothing, Position[list, p]] @ list
```

{{0, 0, 2}, {0, 2, 0}, {2, 0, 0}}

Using `Delete`

```
Delete[list, Position[list, p]]
```

{{0, 0, 2}, {0, 2, 0}, {2, 0, 0}}

Answer (score 1):

```
list = {{0, 0, 2}, {0, 1, 1}, {0, 2, 0}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 0}, {2, 0, 0}};
```

---

Using `SequenceCases`:

```
SequenceCases[list, {s : {a__ /; ! AnyTrue[{a}, OddQ], b_}} :> s]

(*{{0, 0, 2}, {0, 2, 0}, {2, 0, 0}}*)
```

Or using `Pick`:

```
Pick[#, ! AnyTrue[#[[;; 2]], OddQ] & /@ #] &@list

(*{{0, 0, 2}, {0, 2, 0}, {2, 0, 0}}*)
```

Or using `DeleteCases`:

```
DeleteCases[list, {a__ /; AnyTrue[{a}, OddQ], b_}]

(*{{0, 0, 2}, {0, 2, 0}, {2, 0, 0}}*)
```

Or using `Cases`:

```
patt = {a__ /; ! AnyTrue[{a}, OddQ], _};

Cases[list, patt]

(*{{0, 0, 2}, {0, 2, 0}, {2, 0, 0}}*)
```

Or using `ReplaceList`:

```
ReplaceList[list, {___, s : {__?EvenQ, _}, ___} :> s]

(*{{0, 0, 2}, {0, 2, 0}, {2, 0, 0}}*)
```

Equivalently using `ReplaceList`:

```
ReplaceList[list, {___, s : {__?(Not@*OddQ), _}, ___} :> s]

(*{{0, 0, 2}, {0, 2, 0}, {2, 0, 0}}*)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
list = {{0, 0, 2}, {0, 1, 1}, {0, 2, 0}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 0}, {2, 0, 
   0}}

Second = #[[2]] &;
f = OddQ@First@#~Or~OddQ@Second@# &;

f /@ list // Pick[list, #, False] &
```

or

```
Select[list, Not@*f]
```

or

```
DeleteCases[_?f][list]
```

---

*Result:*

{{0, 0, 2}, {0, 2, 0}, {2, 0, 0}}